# MSAL Frontend/backend

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-identity-platform

I have 2 applications (let's call them `frontend`/`backend`) written in .NET 6 with MSAL authentication. `Backend` is an API and frontend is a Razor pages application (which calls the backend).  I need to allow for roles in `backend` (i.e. `User`, `Admin` etc) and therefore `frontend`.  I am using Bearer authentication (MSAL web api) in the backend and MSAL web app in the frontend. In summary, how do I setup these 2 applications in Azure AD and in .NET?

Comment: Let me know if you still have the same question cause I just went through the same questions you had and I could make a post about it but it's a lengthy one.

Comment: I still have the question somewhat (I solved it by just using the same app registration for frontend and backend and `{ClientId}/.default` as the scope and `ClientId` as the JWT Audience). This works, but is obviously not the most professional way to go about it.

Comment: Per the doc you need to create 2 separate token : 

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/acquire-token.md

That' what I'm doing, I have a FrontEnd that get's a token for GraphApi and I'm fetching a different one for my backend API, a C# WebApi, that is hosted on Azure.

I have 2 App Registration one for each in Azure.